# Nested MYSQL group by MONTH, YEAR

Tags: mysql, nested

Noob question for nested query. Having a little issue with this SQL query.  Please help. Trying to COUNT 2 fields in the same table and group by month, year.  Query returns same results in new and renewal fields.

```
SELECT MONTH(p.created_at) as Month, YEAR(p.created_at) as Year,
  (SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM payments p 
INNER JOIN carts c ON c.payment_id = p.id
INNER JOIN cart_items ci on ci.cart_id = c.id 
WHERE ci.item_id = 8) as 'New',
  (SELECT COUNT(p.id) FROM payments p 
INNER JOIN carts c ON c.payment_id = p.id
INNER JOIN cart_items ci on ci.cart_id = c.id 
WHERE ci.item_id = 13) as 'Renewal',     
FROM payments p   
GROUP BY month, year
```

Thanks for the help!

Query Expample

```
Month Year   New    Renewal
1     2010   1169   556
1     2011   1169   556
1     2012   1169   556
2     2010   1169   556
2     2011   1169   556
```

Comment: Provide some example data and it will be easier to answer. Show us what the result of this query is and what result you want it to be.

Comment: Yes, please show us some example data. Also, what happens if you take out the subqueries and run them on their own? It looks like the only difference is `ci.item_id` being 8 or 13, right? Is this the correct number for `new` or `renewal` in your database?

Comment: Added sample data from above query.  Item_id = 8 is a new in db and 13 is renewal in db.  If I pull a simple select without adding in the second product all data comes out like I wanted. Looks like @nishant answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at your query I'm guessing you have a items table which holds various possible purchasable items. Of which item_id = 8 corresponds to a "New" product and item_id = 13 corresponds to a "Renewal".

items are associated with the event of a prospective sale in a relation table called cart_items.

But not all carts are sold, but we only want to look at carts which are actually sold and so we're starting with the payments table.

Whether a prospective sale is paid for or not is recorded in the carts table by populating the payment_id.

A payment represents a cart that has been sold, we get the payments.id from payments, we take the payment_id to carts table and get the cart_id which we take to the cart_items table and get the actual items that were sold, and we want to count it separately if the item_id is 8 ('New') / 13 ('Renewal')

The query we're trying to run then is:

```
SELECT MONTH(p.created_at) as Month,
       YEAR(p.create_at) as Year,
       sum(if(ci.item_id = 8, 1, 0)) as New,
       sum(if(ci.item_id = 13, 1, 0)) as Renewal
  FROM payments p,
       INNER JOIN carts c on c.payment_id = p.id
       INNER JOIN cart_items ci on ci.cart_id = c.id
 WHERE ci.item_id in (8,13)
 GROUP BY month, year;
```

We get the entire data set, we group by the fields we want to group by and we total it up by counting the number of times we see item_id = 8 / item_id = 13.

I might have misunderstood the problem domain so please let me know if you need clarification or if I've gotten something wrong.

Comment: thanks for the above query, you understood perfectly.. forgot about if statements in querys.  Can you explain the ,1 , 0 in the if statement?

Comment: Sorry hadn't checked here in a while. We only want to count the one's that fulfill the if condition, so we set them as 1 for true and 0 for false then when we use the sum function (instead of count) we get the count of values for which if condition is true. Does that help?